# Getting an unexpected 'Symbol not found' error when trying to Base64 encode a string with LuaJIT FFI bindings to OpenSSL's BIO_f_base64()

Tags: c, lua, openssl, ffi, luajit

I am trying to convert this example (found [here](https://www.openssl.org/docs/man1.0.2/crypto/BIO_f_base64.html)) from the openssl documentation to work with LuaJIT's FFI. Scroll down for complete Lua code.

```
BIO *bio, *b64;
char message[] = "Hello World \n";

b64 = BIO_new(BIO_f_base64());
bio = BIO_new_fp(stdout, BIO_NOCLOSE);
BIO_push(b64, bio);
BIO_write(b64, message, strlen(message));
BIO_flush(b64);

BIO_free_all(b64);
```

But when I get to this line in the code `ssl.BIO_flush(b64)`I am getting the error below (running this from the LuaJIT interpreter and not a file)

`stdin:1: Symbol not found: BIO_flush
stack traceback:
        [C]: in function '__index'
        stdin:1: in main chunk
        [C]: at 0x0ac2cdd2f176`

I understand that there are many other ways to do base64 encoding and at this point I have switched to a pure Lua solution. I still would like to understand why I'm getting this error because in part I'm working on this project to learn more about the LuaJIT FFI interface and openssl is already a dependency for libcurl which I am already using (hitting various APIs with OAth and I want to keep my dependencies as lean as possible).

I have already been successful at using openssl's `HMAC()` authentication function (found [here)](https://www.openssl.org/docs/man1.0.2/crypto/hmac.html) from LuaJIT's FFI so through reading documentation and trial and error I am pretty familiar with LuaJIT's FFI interface. Lua code below. I had to navigate through *MANY* openssl header files to get to this `ffi.cdef[[]]` but seems like maybe I'm still missing something. Any help would be appreciated.

**EDIT**: Just to test if the `BIO_flush()` is somehow optional, I've also excluded that line and gone all the way through my code with no errors but then I check the output file and it is blank.

```
ffi = require "ffi"

ffi.cdef[[
typedef struct bio_method_st BIO_METHOD;
typedef struct bio_st BIO;

typedef void bio_info_cb(BIO *, int, const char *, int, long, long);
struct crypto_ex_data_st { struct stack_st_void *sk; };
typedef struct crypto_ex_data_st CRYPTO_EX_DATA;
typedef void CRYPTO_RWLOCK;

typedef long (*BIO_callback_fn)(BIO *b, int oper, const char *argp, int argi,long argl, long ret);
typedef long (*BIO_callback_fn_ex)(BIO *b, int oper, const char *argp,size_t len, int argi,long argl, int ret, size_t *processed);

struct bio_st { const BIO_METHOD *method; BIO_callback_fn callback; BIO_callback_fn_ex callback_ex; char *cb_arg;int init; int shutdown; int flags;int retry_reason; int num; void *ptr; struct bio_st *next_bio;struct bio_st *prev_bio;int references; uint64_t num_read; uint64_t num_write; CRYPTO_EX_DATA ex_data; CRYPTO_RWLOCK *lock; };
struct bio_method_st { int type; const char *name; int (*bwrite) (BIO *, const char *, size_t, size_t *); int (*bwrite_old) (BIO *, const char *, int); int (*bread) (BIO *, char *, size_t, size_t *); int (*bread_old) (BIO *, char *, int); int (*bputs) (BIO *, const char *); int (*bgets) (BIO *, char *, int); long (*ctrl) (BIO *, int, long, void *); int (*create) (BIO *); int (*destroy) (BIO *); long (*callback_ctrl) (BIO *, int, bio_info_cb *); };

typedef struct { char *fpos; void *base; unsigned short handle; short flags; short unget; unsigned long alloc; unsigned short buffincrement; } FILE;

BIO *BIO_new(BIO_METHOD *type);
BIO *BIO_new_fp(FILE *stream, int close_flag);
BIO *BIO_push(BIO *b, BIO *append);
int BIO_write(BIO *b, const void *data, int dlen);
int BIO_read(BIO *b, void *buf, int len);
int BIO_flush(BIO *b);
void BIO_free_all(BIO *a);

BIO_METHOD *BIO_f_base64(void);

FILE *fopen(const char *filename, const char *mode);
int fprintf(FILE *stream, const char *format, ...);
int fclose(FILE *stream);
]]

BIO_NOCLOSE = 0 --# define BIO_NOCLOSE 0x00
BIO_CLOSE = 1 --# define BIO_CLOSE 0x01

ssl = ffi.load('/usr/lib/libssl.so')
f = ffi.C.fopen("/tmp/test", "a+")
bio = ffi.new('BIO')
b64 = ffi.new('BIO')
str = "Hello World"
b64 = ssl.BIO_new(ssl.BIO_f_base64())
bio = ssl.BIO_new_fp(f, BIO_NOCLOSE)
ssl.BIO_push(b64, bio)
=ssl.BIO_write(b64, str, #str) --This yields 11 in the Lua interpreter. This function returns an int with the number of bytes successfully written so apparently the string was written to the file.
ssl.BIO_flush(b64)
ssl.BIO_free_all(b64)

ffi.C.fclose(f)
```